# Neater binary file processing in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is a general question inspired by a particular piece of code I wrote that I'm not happy with. I'm using Data.Binary.Get to grab some data from a binary file. Some of the code looks a bit like this

```
import Data.Binary.Get

data Thing = Thing
  {
    aaa :: Integer,
    bbb :: Integer,
    ccc :: Integer
  } deriving (Show)

getThing :: Get Thing
getThing = do
  laaa <- getWord8 >>= \x -> return (toInteger x)
  lbbb <- getWord16host >>= \x -> return (toInteger x)
  lccc <- getWord32host >>= \x -> return (toInteger x)
  return $ Thing laaa lbbb lccc
```

The "getThing" function is really long. I am hoping there is a nice way to do something like the following pseudocode or maybe something even more concise.

```
[laaa, lbbb, lccc] <- MAGIC [getword8, getword16, getWord32] >>= \x -> return (toInteger x)
```

What have you got?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write

```
getThing :: Get Thing
getThing = Thing <$> intFrom getWord8 <*> intFrom getWord16 <*> intFrom getWord32
  where
    where intFrom x = toInteger <$> x
```

The magic you are looking for is known as [`sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:sequence), but you can't put `IO Word8`, `IO Word16` and `IO Word32` in the same list:

```
getThing :: Get Thing
getThing = do
  [laaa, lbbb, lccc] <- sequence [toInteger <$> getword8, toInteger <$> getword16, toInteger <$> getWord32]
  return $ Thing laaa lbbb lccc
```

Comment: Also, note that for the version using the shorthand `intFrom`, for obscure reasons you'll need to either turn on the `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` pragma or give `intFrom` an explicit type signature (e.g., `intFrom :: (Functor f, Integral a) => f a -> f Integer`).

Comment: Thanks! I went with your first suggestion. It's much easier to read than what I had when laid out over multiple lines with comments on each line.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Thanks, I completely forgot about that. Not putting `intFrom` in a top-level declaration should work as well, right?

Comment: @Bergi, that would have the same problem, as I think you discovered.  But an even nicer solution is probably to write `where intFrom x = toInteger <$> x`.  Giving `intFrom` an explicit argument changes the typing rules slightly, so the monomorphism restriction no longer applies.